# How to specify in Eclipse what to include in a .WAR file

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

In eclipse developing a java app, there are several class files that are generated by a custom ant script. This happens automatically, and it is set up as an export/publish dependency for /WEB-INF/classes. 
With publishing it happens alright, however on exporting to .WAR these files just got missing. 
Is there a way to automate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest generating your war file using Ant.

I like my deliverables to be easy to generate using a simple toolchain, i.e. not need to fire up Eclipse to generate them; this way things are easier to automate and document.

six years after edit: I was an Ant man when I wrote this- today I'd probably suggest Maven

Comment: Well, six years passed, I've left Eclipse behind, and won't look back. However one lesson learned: never depend on the IDE for important tasks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the project properties you will export.
2. Setup the Java EE Module Dependencies

Now they should exist in your exported war.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to add an extra builder. Go to project properties, and then "builders". You can add your own commands which will be run after the eclipse building process runs.

It's not an ideal solution, but maybe it works.